# Multiple Photo Uploads on Facebook Page Timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to publish more than one photo on Page Timeline, but do not see any way how to manage it. I can publish only one photo on Page Timeline or album.

Is there any chance how to upload multiple photos into Page Post in help with Graph API?

Comment: No, that is currently not possible via API. You will have to post each photo individually.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: As found out, not worked successfully, because there were changes.** [More info here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516241/facebook-graph-api-2017-image-uploaded-to-timeline-photos-instead-of-given-alb/41611147#41611147)

---

This is an old post, and I don't know if this method could work back in 2014, but in 2017 it's working. Unfortunately there's no way to create the post in one FB query, but there's a trick.

**Step 1**

Batch upload the images in silent mode, which means there will be no post on the timeline, just pure upload.

For this you have to use

```
'published' => false,
```

in the parameters, and

```
/me/photos
```

as the URL.

**Step 2**

After each upload FB will give you back the ID of the uploaded image. Grab those into an array:

```
$resparr[] = $graphNode['id'];
```

**Step 3**

After the uploads you will have an array of the image IDs. Let's format them for the FB post:

```
$phc = 0;
foreach ($resparr as $pid) {
    $linkData['attached_media['.$phc.']'] = (object)array('media_fbid'=>$pid);
    $phc++;
}
```

**Step 4**

Make an other call to the API, but this time the URL should be

```
/me/feed
```

This will create a public post which contains the images.

(You need a page access token for this to post onto a page, or a user access token to post your wall.)

More info @ [Faceook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads).